# Select specific slides from existing .PPT from a required index in excel document, can this be done?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-powerpoint

How can I select relevant slides only from .ppt from an excel index (below)?

Has anyone solved this?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for a macro that opens a Powerpoint, scrapes the slide title, and creates a table of contents into Excel?

Comment: It feels like this is definitely workable in VBA. What is your expected output, is it another ppt file, a pdf or something else?

Comment: What do you want to do with the "relevant slides"?

Comment: Anecdotal: I once made an Excel file that created a PPT from scratch with over 100 slides, each populated with data form Excel. Controlling PPT from VBA within Excel is 100% doable. I imagine you could have your VBA open the source file in PPT, create a blank PPT file, and copy over just the slides you want. There's some confusion about exactly what you want, though. Can you clarify what it means to "select" a slide? Do you mean a link to go straight to that slide? Making a new PPT with those slides in it? Hiding all but those slides in a current PPT?

Comment: YES anecdotal, EXACTLY THIS, thank god i found you!

Comment: @mattkearney you have been given several options across multiple comments and even the last comment has a couple of options. You should [edit] your question to state explicitly what you are trying to achieve and, if possible, what you have tried so far.

Comment: So, once i am left with the slides i need specifically to the clients scenario then i can export to them in pdf format. Apologies if i have not explained my self very well, but i am limited in my user skills.

Comment: Would it be accurate to say "For each column where the user has chosen YES, I want to select from a larger presentation, the slide called out in the column to the right of the row with YES and create a new presentation, which would then be saved as PDF"?  If so, the simplest solution would be to build an array of the desired slide numbers, save a copy of the BIG presentation to a new file name, open that and step through the slides BACKWARDS ... if the slide number isn't included in the array, delete it. You're left with just the slides the user selected. Save as PDF.

Comment: Steve Rindsberg you are 100% correct in your understanding, and yes i agree with what should be the method of acheieving this. Is that a VBA you could write? or do you know someone who could? My VBA skills are in the realm of beginner! and i honestly would not know where to begin! I hope you can help! I'm desperate!